# Windows 10 professional : Docker Service unfortunately stops

Tags: windows, docker, windows-10

I use chocolatey - window package manager, to download Docker Desktop 2.1.0.2

I type `choco install docker-desktop` to install Docker

All files are downloaded and installed. When Docker Desktop comes to execution, The pop-up "Service is not running" is kept prompting. Docker command cannot be found on elevated cmd and powershell as well. Would you please tell me what condition shall be considered besides closing McAfee shall be considered in order to make the successful installation? I define it as successful image can be created by the command:

```
Docker run hello-world
```

[image]

The second screen shows my OS details:

[image]

When I click "Start" . it shows the following dialog : 
[image]

Comment: Does it work when you click "Start" in that pop up or what happens? Also, do you know if chocolatey adds the installed packages to your PATH? You need this in order to run docker from cmd

Comment: Please see my edited post.

Comment: Looks like maybe you missed something during installation. Can you post the choco commands you used?

Comment: choco install docker-desktop

Comment: Maybe this helps https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3990#issuecomment-496345838